# Pass environment variables to Ant build.xml from Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-cli

I am using Jenkins as CI. I have an build.xml. `Build.xml` has code like below.

```
<property name="environment" value="$environment}" />
```

How can i pass value to build.xml from Jenkins ? Can i pass it through environment variables?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set properties with build parameters (ie: myParameter) and get them in an ant script with `${myParameter}`.

Just make sure you don't use dots in parameters names in jenkins because there might be problems getting them in the ant script.

As for environment variables, i don't know, sorry.

Comment: neomega, "You can set properties with build parameters (ie: myParameter) and get them in an ant script with ${myParameter}." i could not understand it. could you please explain me how to do?

Comment: I answered "How can i pass value to build.xml from Jenkins ?". Jenkins adds all of the build parameters of the job to the ant build : `$ ant -file build_jenkins.xml -Dversion=7.1 -DsendFtp=true`. These parameters values are in the ant properties `${version}` and `${sendFtp}`

Answer (score 14):

Your environment variables are available via the environment property.
In the example below, the environment variable **VIEW** is printed from the simple hello world ant script via **${env.VIEW}**. Change VIEW to the name of the environment variable of interest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Hello World" default="Hello" basedir=".">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="HelloText" value="Hello"/>
    <target name="Hello">
        <echo>VIEW=${env.VIEW}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

**IMPORTANT!** Note that this line is needed in order for `env.VIEW` to be understood by ant:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here..But I tried to leverage a Jenkins variable like NODE_NAME or NODE_LABELS in Ant and it did not work. Using ${env.NODE_NAME}

Comment: You need to set the <property environment="env"/> before you can leverage any of the Jenkins variables. I see that now... Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If your ant build dependeds on the property `environment`:

```
<property
  name="environment"
  value="a_value_I_edit_just_before_run_ant_default_target_mannually" />
```

you could configure your Jenkins' job to build with parameter:
[image]

so Jenkins will log (i.e. on Windows) something like:

```
cmd.exe /C '"ant.bat ant -file build.xml -Djenkins_environment=myValue && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
```

Then you could modify your ant build to check for system property:

```
<property
  name="manually_edited_environment"
  value="a_value_I_edit_just_before_run_ant_default_target_manually" />

<condition property="environment"
           value="${jenkins_environment}"
           else="${manually_edited_environment}">
    <isset property="jenkins_environment" />
</condition>
```

if the `jenkins_environment` property is set then `environment` gets its value, else `environment` gets `manually_edited_environment`'s value; the remaining part of your build still depend on the property `environment`.

If you have trouble in correctly matching the `-DpropertyName` use the [echoproperties ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) to make ant logging all system properties.

Answer (score 0):

your ant script should look like this:-

```
<target name="test" >
    <property environment="env" />
    <echo>BUILD_NUMBER: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</echo>
</target>
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering parametrized build as in the case above e.g you must have set variable called `environment` in the job and getting its value from user.Now you can refer to its value in build.xml using `property name="environment" value="$environment}`